# Wrong quantity or types of arguments error while using dbms_output.put_line in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with the command `dbms_output.put_line()`.

I have a variable `pres_name` and I would like to print the value on the screen. Therefore I use `dbms_output.put_line()` but the command doesn't accept this type of  Variable but all sites that I found they use it like `dbms_output.put_line(varchar variable)`.
But I get this warning:

> Fehler(15,5): please-00306: Falsche Anzahl oder Typen von Argumenten in Aufruf von 'PUT'

In English:

> wrong quantity or types of arguments on the invocation of put

I use Oracle sql developer.

The code:

```
create or replace
procedure ex10_1
(
 pr_name varchar
)
as
cursor pres is select vice_pres_name from admin_pr_vp;
begin
  open pres;
  for pr_name in pres loop
    dbms_output.put_line(pr_name);
  end loop;
end;
```

ps: the code is not perfect yet.

Comment: Are you typing `varchar`, too? You need just `dbms_output.put_line(your_variable)`. Try a simpler thing first: `dbms_output.put_line('hello, world')`.

Comment: no write it right and  the comand works if i write a text as argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<snip>
for pr_name in pres loop
    dbms_output.put_line(pr_name);
end loop;
<snip>
```

In PL/SQL a [cursor for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm) implicitly declares the loop variable to be a record type matching a row of the cursor. So, within the loop `pr_name` is a record with a single field, `vice_pres_name`. That field has type `vice_pres_name%TYPE`. This inner `pr_name` shadows the outer `pr_name` argument. DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE takes a varchar2 and PL/SQL is not able to implicitly convert the `pr_name` record.

Here is an example anonymous that uses an cursor for loop and the record syntax to print the values returned by a cursor:

```
SQL>     declare
  2          cursor pres is select 'A' as vice_pres_name
  3              from dual union all select 'B' from dual;
  4      begin <<ex10_1>>
  5          for pr_name in pres loop
  6              dbms_output.put_line(pr_name.vice_pres_name);
  7          end loop;
  8      end ex10_1;
  9  /
A
B

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Also note, that a cursor for loop implicitly opens and closes the cursor for you.